# How do I merge local changes if any (other changes otherwise) in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge

There are two heads on my repository. I have five files that I've edited locally. The Bitbucket repo has 15 changed files that I haven't edited, but it also contains changed versions of the same 5 files.

I'd like to do the following:

1) If I've edited a file and the Bitbucket repo contains the same edited file, I'd like my changes to take preference.

2) If I haven't edited a file, I'd like to update to the latest version.

What sequence of commands in Mercurial will let me do this? Do I have to use an external program?

Comment: Have you gone through http://hginit.com or a similar tutorial? It seems you're a bit off in the workflow here.

Comment: Have you committed your changes locally? Have you tried to pull and merge?

Comment: Yes I committed the changes locally (creating a new head). This is what happens if I have a newer version on the Bitbucket repo, but I forgot to pull and merge before making changes.

Answer (score 1):

**WITH LOCAL COMMITS**

```
hg pull
hg update --rev ${my version}
hg merge --rev ${their version} --tool internal:local
```

See also `hg help merge-tools`

**WITHOUT LOCAL COMMITS**

`hg status -qn` gives you a list of files you have changed.  Since it's only five files, I'd copy them away manually, then revert, pull, update and copy them back into place.  On unix you could write a throw-away shell script, something that goes kinda' like this:

```
ls -l *.mine # check to see that there are none
for file in `hg status -qn`; do cp ${file} ${file}.mine; done
hg revert --all; hg pull; hg update
for file in *.mine; do cp ${file} ${file%.mine}; done
```

This is untested code.  Run it at your own risk.  Eat muffins and be happy.

Answer (score -1):

just do

```
hg pull
hg merge
```

This will pull the latest changes from bitbucket and allow you to merge your local changes the way you want.

This is really a basic functionality, you should read some documentation about mercurial, for example [HG Init](http://hginit.com/)  like said in the comments.

Comment: No, this is not what I am trying to describe. My version of the repository hasn't been updated in a while so there are conflicting versions of each file. When I try to run `hg merge`, Mercurial reports that the merge failed.

Comment: @Kevin the *automatic* merge failed, you  must know tell Mercurial what to do, using for example `hg resolve`. You should *really* read some documentation, what you're trying to go is *basic manipulation*

Comment: I know you can resolve it and specify a merge editor. I was wondering if there was a way to resolve it automatically. Just typing `hg resolve` in the Terminal spits back that Mercurial was unable to resolve the differences.

Comment: krtek, sorry, but your reply is summarily unhelpful, and your tone is condescending. I've seen many questions on Stack asking even more basic than Burke's, but typically a patient soul explains it anyway (and often gets a load of points).

Comment: @labyrinth Seems there's a shortage of patient soul to answer this question or the all judged that my answer was good enough. My tone may be condescending, but there's no better answer than this, you pull, you merge, you resolve the conflicts, there's no other magical way to do what the OP asks.